# Problem with \tabular in booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have a master document with the following packages.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}%Rahmen der Titelseite
\usepackage{textpos}%Befehl \begin{textblock}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Für die schönen Tabellen
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{url}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm,right=30mm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm} 
%\pagestyle{fancy}
    %\fancyhead[OR]{\chaptermark}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{fnpos}
```

I can't get the following lines to work:

```
\begin{table} 
\centering
\caption{Messwerte für die spez. Wärmekapazität des Kalorimeters}
\label{Tab:Waermekap:Kal}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}} %p{Spaltenbreite} 
\toprule
 \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Wert}\\
\midrule
$m_\text{Warmw.}$ & $0{,}0602$\,kg\\
$m_\text{Kaltw.}$ & $0{,}1693$\,kg\\
$m_\text{Kal}$ & $0{,}2355$\,kg\\
$T_\text{Mittel}$ & $311{,}15$\,K\\
$T_\text{Kaltw.}$ & $297{,}45$\,K\\
$T_\text{Warmw.}$ & $353{,}15$\,K\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

When trying to compile, TexMaker sends me the error:

> "! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble. &l.91 \begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{3cm}}%p{Spaltenbreite} "

Does anyone see the mistake?

Comment: please fix your example, deleting the packages not needed for this problem and making it into a document that can be run to demonstrate the error.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make this into a complete minimal example (makes it a lot easier for others to help. (3) for large sections of code indent each line with 4 spaces (tip in the browser you can mark the code and press ctrl-k this indents all marked lines with 4 spaces). (4) learn to use the siunitx package to typeset units and their values, it can be told to use German traditions. (5) don't use `\text` this way, it is not what that macro is meant for.

Answer (score 4):

The `ftnxtra` appears to break tabular. This works without error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs} %Für die schönen Tabellen

\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{fnpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\centering
\caption{Messwerte für die spez. Wärmekapazität des Kalorimeters}
\label{Tab:Waermekap:Kal}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}} %p{Spaltenbreite} 
\toprule
 \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Wert}\\
\midrule
$m_\text{Warmw.}$ & $0{,}0602$\,kg\\
$m_\text{Kaltw.}$ & $0{,}1693$\,kg\\
$m_\text{Kal}$ & $0{,}2355$\,kg\\
$T_\text{Mittel}$ & $311{,}15$\,K\\
$T_\text{Kaltw.}$ & $297{,}45$\,K\\
$T_\text{Warmw.}$ & $353{,}15$\,K\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Curious, as `ftnxtra` “fixes the issue of footnote inside `\caption{}`, `tabular` environment”, according to its short documentation.

Comment: @egreg I suspect it patches the format tabular and trips up on array package version, but I'm not too motivated to trace it too far,

Answer (score 3):

The `ftnxtra` is incompatible with the `array` package, which is loaded by `siunitx`. This is a stopper for using the package: `array` is among the “standard” LaTeX tools (albeit being optional).

Several packages load `array`, because it helps in building tables more complex than the types allowed by the kernel functions.

What happens is that `ftnxtra` redefines `\@tabular` but it's too late for doing it, if `array` has already been loaded.

You can load it before `siunitx` and any other package loading `array`, but I'm not sure it will do what it claims to.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Für die schönen Tabellen
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage[
  hyperfootnotes=false,% doesn't work with fnpos and ftnxtra
]{hyperref}

\sisetup{locale=DE} % German conventions for numbers

\setlength{\textheight}{8cm} % just to minimize output

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\centering
\caption{Messwerte für die spez. Wärmekapazität des Kalorimeters\footnote{Xyz}}
\label{Tab:Waermekap:Kal}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}S[table-format=1.1]} %p{Spaltenbreite} 
\toprule
 \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Wert}\\
\midrule
$m_\text{Warmw.}$            & \SI{0,0602}{\kilo\gram} & 1.1\\
$m_\text{Kaltw.}$            & \SI{0,1693}{\kilo\gram} & 0.1\\
$m_\text{Kal}$\footnote{Abc} & \SI{0,2355}{\kilo\gram}\\
$T_\text{Mittel}$            & \SI{311,15}{\kelvin}\\
$T_\text{Kaltw.}$            & \SI{297,45}{\kelvin}\\
$T_\text{Warmw.}$            & \SI{353,15}{\kelvin}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I added an `S` column just for testing, and some footnotes. Note that units should be input using `\SI`.

[image]

A couple of notes.

1. `hyperref` should be loaded last (only a few packages need to go after it)
2. Both `ftnxtra` and `fnpos` play with footnotes, so the hyperlinks break; hence it's necessary to disable them with `hyperfootnotes=false`: the effect is the same, that is, no hyperlinks, but, at least, you don't get annoying warnings.